# Area of intersection of two rectangles

Tags: c++, algorithm

I came across this interesting piece of code. It calculates the overlapping area of two rectangles.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int overlapLine(int p11, int p12, int p21, int p22)
{
    int buf;

    buf = p11;
    p11 = min(p11, p12);
    p12 = max(buf, p12);

    buf = p21;
    p21 = min(p21, p22);
    p22 = max(buf, p22);

    return  max(0, max(0, p12 - p21) - max(0, p11 - p21) - max(0, p12 - p22));
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x11 = -5, y11 = -5, x12 = 5,  y12 = 5;
    int x21 = -1, y21 = -1, x22 = 1,  y22 = 1;

    int w = overlapLine(x11, x12, x21, x22);
    int h = overlapLine(y11, y12, y21, y22);

    int overlapArea = w * h;
    cout << "OVERLAP AREA: " << overlapArea << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code works and produces correct result. However, I cannot understand how *overlapLine* gets the correct overlapping by X and Y axis.

Comment: I think I'd rewrite this as `if (p11 > p12) swap(p11, p12); if (p21 > p22) swap(p21, p22); return max(min(p12, p22) - max(p11, p21), 0);`

Comment: The code is probably intended to be a micro-optimized version of the overlap calculation. But it fails miserably as optimization, and horribly obfuscates the calculations in the process. The code invokes `min` and `max` a total of 8 times, and requires 5 subtractions. Properly written and easy to read code would invoke `min` and `max` a total of 7 times, and only require 1 subtraction.

Comment: It is not an optimization related code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this answers your question:
[image]

Comment: I guess the swapping is needed to 'normalize' the input so that the formula would hold even in negative axis. It also probably uses min/max for swapping because some assignment said not to use conditional operators at all. Interesting non-standard approach though.

Comment: @Eval agreed. i forgot to mention the swapping.